# preprocessing the text and excluding form footnotes , extra spaces and

Tags: python, regex

I need to clean my corpus, it includes these problems

- multiple spaces  --> Tables  .
- footnote         --> 10h 50m,1
- unknown ”        --> replace " instead of ”
  e.g

for instance, you see it here:

```
On 1580 November 12 at 10h 50m,1 they set Mars down at 8° 36’ 50” Gemini2 without mentioning the horizontal variations, by which term I wish the diurnal parallaxes and the refractions to be understood in what follows. Now this observation is distant and isolated. It was reduced to the moment of opposition using the diurnal motion from the Prutenic Tables  .
```

I have done it using these functions

```
def fix4token(x):
    x=re.sub('”', '\"', x)
    if (x[0].isdigit()== False )| (bool(re.search('[a-zA-Z]', x))==True ):
        res=x.rstrip('0123456789')
        output = re.split(r"\b,\b",res, 1)[0]
        return output  
    else:
        return x
```

```
def removespaces(x):
    res=x.replace("  ", " ")
    return(res)
```

it works not bad for this but the result is so

```
On 1580 November 12 at 10h 50m, they set Mars down at 8° 36’ 50" Gemini without mentioning the horizontal variations,  by which term I wish the diurnal parallaxes and the refractions to be understood in what follows. Now this observation is distant and isolated. It was reduced to the moment of opposition using the diurnal motion from the Prutenic Tables.
```

but the problem is it damaged other paragraphs. it does not work ver well,

I guess because this break other things

```
x=re.sub('”', '\"', x)
    if (x[0].isdigit()== False )| (bool(re.search('[a-zA-Z]', x))==True ):
        res=x.rstrip('0123456789')
        output = re.split(r"\b,\b",res, 1)[0]
```

what is the safest way to do these?

1- remove footnotes like in these phrases

- "10h 50m,1" or    (extra foot note in text after comma)
- "Gemini2"        (zodic names of month + footnote)

without changing another part of the text (e.g my approach will break the "DC2"  to "DC" which is not desired

2- remove multiple spaces before dot . like   "Tables  ."  to no spaces
or  remove multiple  before, like:    ",  by which term"  to this 9only one space) ", by which term"

3-replace unknown ”   -> replace "  ...which is done

thank you

Comment: This is not clear. What exact problem are you having?

Comment: basically how you remove footnote, spaces and replace  " instead of ”

Comment: Try `re.sub(r'\s*\d{1,2}h\s?\d{1,2}m(?:,\d+)?|\s{2,}', '', text).replace('”', '"')`

Comment: thank you for your message that does not work and removed the whole token 

```
On 1580 November 12 at, they set Mars down at 8° 36’ 50" Gemini without mentioning the horizontal variations,by which term I wish the diurnal parallaxes and the refractions to be understood in what follows.
```

Comment: thank you, this does not work for footnote and remove the whole token before the footnote, the problem

Comment: If you need tangible help, please consider putting effort into explaining *in plain clear English* what you need.

Comment: ok, I have edited my post ..main points are: 

1- remove footnotes like in these phrases   

- "10h 50m,1" or    (extra foot note in text after comma)
- "Gemini2"        (zodic name of month + footnote)

 without changing another part of the text (e.g my approach will break the "DC2"  to "DC" which is not desired

2- remove multiple spaces before dot . like   "Tables  ."  to no spaces
or  remove multiple  before, like:    ",  by which term"  to this 9only one space) ", by which term"

3-replace unknown ”   -> replace "  ...which is done

Comment: Try `re.sub(r'\b(?:,\d+|(Capricorn|Aquarius|Pisces|Aries|Taurus|Gemini|Cancer|Leo|Virgo|Libra|Scorpio|Ophiuchus|Sagittarius)\d+)\b|\s+(?=[.,])', r'\1', text, flags=re.I).replace('”', '"')`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/yvQqGk/2).

Comment: thank you for your comment that looks to work better than mine, but still a minor thing, I want to remove the footnote and not  ", "or "."

Comment: Sorry, you keep saying "footnote" but I have no idea what it is.

Comment: thank you for the quickj response, I meant  "1" in "10h 50m,1"   ...this is a footnote but it is not written as a footnote, so I want to remove 1  and  not the comma,

Comment: Ok, so how can we determine if the number is a footnote or not? If my regex above is fine overall and you just want to keep the comma, put it into a lookbehind, `re.sub(r'\b(?:(?<=,)\d+|(Capricorn|Aquarius|Pisces|Aries|Taurus|Gemini|Cancer|Leo|Virgo|Libra|Scorpio|Ophiuchus|Sagittarius)\d+)\b|\s+(?=[.,])', r'\1', text, flags=re.I).replace('”', '"')`

Comment: that was very nice!! many thanks, I have still some double space after the comma 
```
, by which term I wish
```

Comment: You can shrink whitespace using `re.sub(r'\s{2,}', ' ', string)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
text = re.sub(r'\b(?:(?<=,)\d+|(Capricorn|Aquarius|Pisces|Aries|Taurus|Gemini|Cancer|Leo|Virgo|Libra|Scorpio|Ophiuchus|Sagittarius)\d+)\b|\s+(?=[.,])', r'\1', text, flags=re.I).replace('”', '"')
text = re.sub(r'\s{2,}', ' ', text)
```

*Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `(?<=,)\d+` - one or more digits that are preceded with a comma
  - `|` - or
  - `(Capricorn|Aquarius|Pisces|Aries|Taurus|Gemini|Cancer|Leo|Virgo|Libra|Scorpio|Ophiuchus|Sagittarius)\d+` - one of the zodiac sign words (captured into Group 1, `\1` in the replacement pattern refers to this value) and then one or more digits
- `)` - the end of the non-capturing group
- `\b`
- `|` - or
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(?=[.,])` - that are immediately followed with `.` or `,`.

The `.replace('”', '"')` replaces all `”` with a `"` char.

The `re.sub(r'\s{2,}', ' ', text)` code replaces all chunks of two or more whitespaces with a single regular space.